# "Висок" чи "скроня"?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

У СУМі знаходжу 2 поняття  [висок](http://sum.in.ua/s/vysok) і [скроня](http://sum.in.ua/s/skronja). Однак, в  [Українсько-російському словнику Дубровського В.](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Dubrovskyi_Viktor/Ukrainsko-rosiiskyi_slovnyk/) бачимо переклад українського **скроня** - рос. **високь**. Чи нормативні ці два слова у сучасній літературній мові. Якщо так, то що вплинуло на таку зміну?

Answer (score 3):

В сучасній анатомічній термінології існує лише "скронева" кістка. Зокрема можна перевірити в "Міжнародна анатомічна термінологія." 2010 рік, за редакцією проф.Черкасова В.Г.

Answer (score 0):

Згідно до СУМу та до словнику на сайті [Академік](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA/ru/uk/) варіант "висок" як синонім до слова "скроня" можливий (а також згідно до цього [джерела](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=39155)). Однак, гадаю, що слід ввживати слово "скроня" у значенні "частина голови за очима, від вуха до чола" (та й на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F)  вказано це як єдиний правильний варіант (також там пише про скроневі, а не вискові отвори та м'язи)), а от слово "висок" краще вживати у значенні "пристосування для позначення в натурі вискової лінії (вертикалі)" знідно до тієї ж [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA).